# Linux machine doesn't wake up from suspend

Tags: linux, suspend, acpi

I moved from the laptop to PC recently and noticed that suspend doesn't work. In particular it acts like:

1. I click «Suspend» and looks like system properly goes to sleep
2. There is a blue LED on the front of the case and it starts to blink slowly. Blinks for 4-5 times (7-10sec) and stops blinking. The usb-wifi connected to mobo has a LED which is active disregard of state of blue LED
3. Click of the power button starts regular boot of my Linux, not restoring the state
4. If I click power button within these 4-5 blinks of the LED, then system restore it states properly with no problem
5. Connection of Corsair HX750 PSU didn't help and didn't affect anything

## HW

Motherboard Asus B150M-PLUS, Intel G4400, M.2 SSD, AMD RX560.
BIOS was updated to the latest 3806 firmware and setting were reset with CLRTC pins.

## Soft

Debian Testing (non-free and non-free-firmware are enabled). Up to date.
Files /var/log/pm-* are empty.

```
# journalctl |grep PM|grep supports
```

```
Mar 10 20:50:43 scif kernel: ACPI: PM: (supports S0 S3 S4 S5)
Mar 10 20:50:43 scif kernel: acpi PNP0A08:00: _OSC: OS supports [ExtendedConfig ASPM ClockPM Segments MSI HPX-Type3
```

Boot log: https://pastebin.com/qzNkhyPz